# Как сделать punycode url'a, не только домен

Tags: perl

Я нашел вариант как преобразовать punycode для домена, но не нашел скрипта, где это было бы для url'a
Примеры: 
домен: президент.рф
url: [http://президент.рф/help/faq.html](http://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/help/faq.html)

вот такой скрипт переводит домен:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use URI;
use URI::UTF8::Punycode;
use Encode;

my $domain = shift;
print puny_encode_domain($domain);

sub puny_encode_domain {
    my $domain = shift;

    my @puny_words = ();
    foreach my $d (split(/\./, $domain)) {
        if ($d !~ m/[a-zA-Z0-9*]/i) {
        $d = puny_enc($d) unless $d =~ m/^\d+$/;
        }
        push(@puny_words, $d);
    }
    my $result = join('.', @puny_words);
    return $result;

}
```

но если ввести [http://президент.рф/help/faq.html](http://%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/help/faq.html) не работает.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно не работает, оно только части домена кодирует. Посмотрите на код функции `puny_encode_domain()`, в ней `split` выдаст вам такие части для целого адреса:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use DDP;
use utf8::all;

my @parts = split /\./, 'http://президент.рф/help/faq.html';
p @parts;
```

Вывод:

```
[
    [0] "http://президент",
    [1] "рф/help/faq",
    [2] "html"
]
```

Соответственно, все они проскочат мимо `puny_enc()`.

Можно всё сделать проще, в модуле [URI](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI) поддержка IDNA уже давно есть из коробки:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use utf8::all;
use URI;

my $uri = URI->new( 'http://президент.рф/help/faq.html' );
say $uri->canonical();
```

Вывод:

```
http://xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai/help/faq.html
```

Comment: Спасибо работает, хотя я по-другому сделал, но так тоже работает :)

Comment: @TRIada, по-другому - проще, чем один метод URI, и без велосипедов? Тогда делитесь, написав ответ на ваш же вопрос.

Comment: Использовал библиотеку Mojo. Но в нем и в вашем скрипте path приводят в канонический вид, типа %D0%BF%D0%BE. Я щас думаю как бы это пофиксить, мне не нужно кодировать path

Answer (score 0):

Еще 1 вариант с библиотекой Mojo::URL

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Mojo::URL;
binmode(STDOUT,':utf8');

    my $data = shift;
    my $url = Mojo::URL->new($data);
    my $path = $url->path;
    my $punyhost = $url->ihost;
    print "$punyhost"."$path"."\n";
```